# Handling strings with linebreaks in vars

Tags: php, javascript, line-breaks

I'm trying to get it once again.

I got a JS var which looks like this:

```
var test;
```

Now I write some JS with PHP:

```
<?php
    $phpvar = "a text with
    a linebreak";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        var test;
        test = '" . $phpvar . "';
    </script>";
?>
```

Now, if I run it, it outputs the source as follows:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var test;
test = 'a text with
a linebreak';
</script>
```

This gives me a JS exception:

```
ERROR: unterminated string literal
```

Somehow, JS seems not to recognize that there is a string on more than one line.

How can I realize this if, in the end, the string must have its linebreak again? (So, if all execution finishes, I must have the string including all linebreaks)

Thank you for your help ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, if you use a \ at the end of a Javascript line, you can use multiple lines within a string.

```
<?php
    $phpvar = "a text with
    a linebreak";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        var test;
        test = '" . str_replace("\n", "\\\n",$phpvar) . "';
    </script>";
?>
```

Comment: maybe replace to `\\\n` because needs a \ which is \\ and a `\n`

Comment: But that won't put actual newlines into the JS string, it will just let the string literal break over several lines. If the intention is for the string to contain newline characters replace `\n` with `\\n` such that by the time the browser see it is is a backslash character followed by an `n`.

Answer (score 1):

escaping in php:

```
js:           php:
<linebreak>   \n
\             \\
\n            \\n
```

If you want this:

```
var test = "te\
st";
console.log(test) > "test"
```

in this case you need to use a `\` and `<linebreak>` (in js), so you need to replace the `\n` to `\\` plus `\n` (in php)

```
<?php
    $phpvar = "a text with
    a linebreak";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        var test;
        test = '" . str_replace("\n", "\\\n",$phpvar) . "';
    </script>";
?>
```

*this keep the linebreaks as a php but not in the javasccript*

---

But if you want to keep the linebreaks in javascript like this:

```
console.log(test) > "te
                     st"
```

You need to add a `\n` as an escaped string, not as a linebreak character.
So the code will look like this

```
var test = "te\n\
st"
console.log(test) > "te
                     st"
```

In this case you need a `\n` and a `\` and a `<linebeak>` (in js), so you need to replace the the `\n` to a `\\n` plus `\\` plus `\n`

```
<?php
    $phpvar = "a text with
    a linebreak";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        var test;
        test = '" . str_replace("\n", "\\n\\\n",$phpvar) . "';
    </script>";
?>
```

*this keeps the linebreaks in php, and also add linebreaks into the javascript*